# Why versions_xid value gets reset after some time in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

While working with row versions query it has been observed the `versions_xid` value gets removed after some time.

For example:

```
SQL> select versions_xid, empno, ename, sal from scott.emp
versions between scn minvalue and maxvalue
order by sal;

VERSIONS_XID          EMPNO ENAME         SAL
---------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
                       7369 SMITH         800
                       7900 JAMES         950
                       7876 ADAMS        1100
                       7521 WARD         1250
                       7654 MARTIN       1250
                       7934 MILLER       1300
                       7839 KING         1400
                       7788 SCOTT        1400
                       7844 TURNER       1500
01002100D6050000       7788 SCOTT        1500
                       7499 ALLEN        1600
                       7566 JONES        1800
0800130073070000       7788 SCOTT        1800
06001500DB070000       7788 SCOTT        1900
04000C00B9060000       7788 SCOTT        2000
                       7782 CLARK        2450
                       7698 BLAKE        2850
                       7902 FORD         3000

18 rows selected.

SQL>
```

After some time when i execute the same query the row versions are gone!

```
SQL> select versions_xid, empno, ename, sal from scott.emp
versions between scn minvalue and maxvalue
order by sal;  2    3  

VERSIONS_XID          EMPNO ENAME         SAL
---------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
               7369 SMITH         800
               7900 JAMES         950
               7876 ADAMS        1100
               7521 WARD         1250
               7654 MARTIN       1250
               7934 MILLER       1300
               7839 KING         1400
               7844 TURNER       1500
               7499 ALLEN        1600
               7566 JONES        1800
               7788 SCOTT        2000
               7782 CLARK        2450
               7698 BLAKE        2850
               7902 FORD         3000

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Can someone please let me know whats happening? Is it something to do with undo_retention? Because, reading through various blogs and Oracle docs didn't give a direct answer or relation.